# Android - generated layouts, is it possible?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

is it possible in Android create dynamic layouts and then use them? I mean insted of layouts defined in src use some dynamic generated layouts from database, which contains pieces of XML code and when put together it makes new layout...

It is real or unreal scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not supported. The built-in `LayoutInflater` requires resource files, not arbitrary XML. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html):

> Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)

You would have to write your own `LayoutInflater` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

you can create elements programatically. For instance you can do:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView();
```

You may have to do something like this. Otherwise you will need to generate an XML file and use `LayoutInflater` I guess.